# javascript pop-up link with page id

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a class = 'printrequest' href="printrequest.php" onclick="javascript:void window.open('printrequest.php?id=$studid','1361194834275','width=800,height=700, toolbar=0,menubar=1,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">PRINT</a>
```

this is a link to redirect my link to print the content of a page.
is this possible? how can i attached the id to redirect the link to the required page id?

Comment: `window.open('printrequest.php?id=$studid` i need to call the ?id=$studid to get the data from my database but its on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could do this I would normally get the url param in the backend and pass it through to the page.

But if you want to use javascript you can use a gup function like

```
function gup( name ){
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");  
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";  
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );  
var results = regex.exec( window.location.href ); 
 if( results == null )    return "";  
else    return results[1];}
```

then

```
<a class = 'printrequest' href="printrequest.php" onclick="javascript:void window.open('printrequest.php?id='+gup('id')+'','1361194834275','width=800,height=700, toolbar=0,menubar=1,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">PRINT</a>
```

Comment: No problem dont forget to mark as the correct answer and good luck with your project.